# What to do if a company if flying me out for a job interview tomorrow but I no longer want to go?

Tags: interviewing

Long story short, I have a job interview tomorrow.
I have a company flying me out to a different state for a series of in-person interviews.

I was interested in the job initially, but have lots of second thoughts about it over the past two 
days. Can I just cancel it now? Or am I obligated to go?

Comment: The answer really depends on why you _have lots of second thoughts_? New info about the company? Your current company gives you a good raise? Or just cold feet?

Comment: Of course you can cancel. Just call and politely tell them you are no longer available.

Answer (score 13):

You're not obligated to go, but why the change of heart? Are you nervous and uncomfortable?

My two cents: if you're like me and doing that kind of thing of scares you, you should definitely go. Expand the bounds of your comfort zone, practice interviewing and hey--you might actually like the job.

Comment: +1 Two opposite answers on this question. I would go to the interview.

Comment: And interview experience is always usefull

Answer (score 5):

Very simply, no. You are not required or obligated to go. In fact, if you truly do not want to go or not interested in the job opportunity, cancel and do not waste your time or the employers time. Although they won't be happy, it would save them time and money to focus on another candidate that is interested.

Note: This probably won't look great on you cancelling last minute, so expect bridges to be burned.